# How to use a for loop to display the type of each value stored against each key in dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, types

```
person = {'Name':'Dustin','Age':19,'HasCar':True}
```

How can I get the following output using for loop:

```
The key "Name" has the value "Dustin" of the type "<class 'str'>"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `items()` function to get both key and value like this

```py
person = {'name':'Dustin','Age':19,'HasCar':True}
for key,val in person.items():
    print(f'The key "{key}" has the value "{val}" of the type "{type(val)}"')
```

output

> The key "name" has the value "Dustin" of the type "<class 'str'>"
>
> The key "Age" has the value "19" of the type "<class 'int'>"
>
> The key "HasCar" has the value "True" of the type "<class 'bool'>"